Winforms controls at 150% scale display renders at wrong location
I have upgraded a winforms program from .net framework 4.7 to .net core 8. When the forms renders at 100% scale displays, it renders correctly. But when it renders at 150%, the positions of the panels gets wrongly located, as shown in the images. I cant understand why it continues to run correctly with .net framework 4.7, but the converted code does not.


Anybody with the same experience? What steps can i perform to understand what is going on and fix it?

I am currently having the form with DPI autoscale mode. I have tried inherit, none and font, and none of them solved the issue.

It seems like there is an issue with horizontal offset of the panels, so they are being pushed to the left.

The solution was to create a new tab, and using the document outline move the panels with the controls to that tab. Then after adjusting the position to the intended location it worked fine. So it seems that the upgrade tool from framework to .net core is somehow buggy.
